# how many simultaneous ajax calls should i call at once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

i have a page that loads a bunch of different windows which each come from different servers.

i do this now by having a number of javascript function firing off ajax calls to different asp.net-mvc controller actions and then all come back independently.

Is there a sweet spot in terms of number of ajax calls to do at once.  At some threshhold, it is better to wait for some to return before kicking off other requests ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big question here is not how many calls, but how many *per server*, that's where connection limits come into play (and the reason people use CDNs with different host names for example).

If the resources are on different host names that go to the same place then you're all set and it'll parallelize nicely in older browsers, newer ones have higher connection limits by default.

*However*, I'm assuming all the requests are hitting the same host name (otherwise the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) kicks in)...in which case your best bet is *still* to just let it go (unless we're talking about 50-100+ requests here) and let the browser parallelize as it sees fit.

Comment: @Nick Craver - what do you mean by "let it go".  So is there anything wrong with kicking off 4-5 ajax requests simultaneous and waiting for the various callbacks?  is there any synchronization or similar to worry about ??

Comment: @ooo - nope, they can all run at once and handle themselves, same with 100 requests...that's what I meant by "let it go" :)

Comment: @ooo - i am seeing some issues where, when i have a number of ajax requests outstanding (server is running some db queries) and then i click to another page, it seems slow.  Would existing ajax calls slow down or block this new page request ??  Do i have to explicitally kills open ajax requests when i move to a new page ??

Comment: @ooo - it depends on the browser, IE in particular might choke a bit on the garbage collection...you can manually abort requests yes, but that's not to say it'll be any faster, they have to be cleaned up either way.  Is it really necessary to do all the requests separately? you can't combine them? (it would be a much better experience for the user).

Comment: @Nick Craver - i agree.. i am looking at combining them into a single ajax request and see how it performs . . .

Comment: @ooo - you should get much more benefit out of that than *any* client optimization, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The browser will limit it for you. Each browser has its predefined amounts of simultaneous parallel connections, parallel connections to the same domain, etc.

There is no best practices in this question afaik.